# Idea 14 Play Scala Project

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a project which was build with typesafe activator and everything was fine until today. My project is on play framework + Scala but idea sees external libraries as .class files. There is no traits, objects, case classes, only .class and interfaces.

I've found that topic: http://www.hnwatcher.com/r/1531217/Scala-Plugin-Update-for-IntelliJ-IDEA-14-RC-Is-Out and I've added scala-sdk as it says

But I still get those .class files.

Important note: My colleague experienced same issue but adding scala-sdk helped him, and all his Idea's External Libraries looks like normal Scala objects, trais, so on..

We use same repo and we have same version of idea intellej

Answer (score 0):

There was strange fact. I had two ideas 13 and 14. I opened my project with 13 version and it was fine! Then i tried to open same project in 14 and i had those .class files again. So it occurred to me that may be there are some settings that 14 version uses from 13 version..

I deleted .IntelliJIdea14 and .IntelliJIdea13 folders in my home folder(~) and then launched idea 14. Then i installed scala-sdk in project structure and it works now!